# remove xml declaration in payload response

Tags: wso2, ei, wso2-esb

I want remove xml declaration from wso response created by payload mediator (post method).

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mgod="MgOdinCToCrm" xmlns:mgex="MgExchange">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <m:getQuote xmlns:m="http://services.samples/xsd">
            <m:request>
                <m:symbol/>
            </m:request>
        </m:getQuote>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I try use xslt and js mediators to modify response, but it isn't help. This mediator can modify content only in body tag. May be someone faced with this problem

Comment: What version are you using? Also, is this an actual problem?

Comment: I use wso2 6.3.0 and I have not solved the problem. I was able to create a custom mediator and delete the xml Declaration, but I don't want to use a custom mediator

Answer (score 3):

Try with setting messageType as follows.

```
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/xml"/>
```

Comment: this did not solve my issue, is there any other way?

Comment: what did you define it under axis2 formatter?